# Radio buttons and text box event handling

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I'm making a page in JSP and am unable to determine how to do the following.

I have a bunch of radio buttons generated dynamically in a for loop

```
<%
for (Something something : somethings) {
    for (Random random : something.getRandoms ()) { %>
        <input type ="radio" name="<%= something%>" value="<%= random.toString()%>"><%= random%> <br>
<% }%>
    Some text here : <input type = "text" name="<%= something%>Text" placeholder="Some more text here"/>
<% }%>
```

What I want to do is:

When one of the radio buttons are checked, the text box should be made empty and when some text is entered in the text box, the radio buttons should be cleared.

I tried in javascript by saying `<name of text box>.value=""`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're having a problem setting the value of text boxes or in the event handling or both?

Comment: Assign a class (say txtBox) to all text boxes and radioBtn to all radios. On click of radio button, get all elements having txtBox class and clear, do the same thing for text box.

Comment: Note that `<input>` elements can't contain content, so the closing `</input>` tags that you've shown are not needed. @Manish - why do you suggest a class when the elements already have a (common) name?

Comment: @Matsemann, the html edits I've made are being made at the OP's request.  Please see comments.  Adding a label does not affect the answer, as he is looking for a JS answer, but will stop comments about the validity of the code.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I don't think that's a valid way of doing stuff. If his code needs changes, you should show how the code should look in your answer, not change the question.

Comment: @Matsemann, in the case of the `label` I have to disagree, as the `label` has no bearing on his answer.  In the case of the `fieldset`, you have a point, but the OP explicitly requested the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this answer assumes you have wrapped a `fieldset` around each grouping of radio buttons and text box:

```
var sets = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset'),
    setsCount = sets.length,
    clearBox = function (box) {
        box.value = '';
    },
    clearFields = function (fieldset) {
        var buttons = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'),
            buttonCount = buttons.length,
            textBox = fieldset.querySelector('input[type="text"]'),
            j;

        for (j = 0; j < buttonCount; j += 1) {
            buttons[j].onclick = function () {
                clearBox(textBox);
            };
        }

        textBox.onkeypress = function () {
            for (j = 0; j < buttonCount; j += 1) {
                buttons[j].checked = false;
            }
        };
    },
    i;

for (i = 0; i < setsCount; i += 1) {
    clearFields(sets[i]);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VjFD/)

Comment: I have multiple groups of radio buttons. So I can't do it this way. Each group (of some radio buttons + 1 text box) is independent. I need a modification of this.

Comment: Put each group in a fieldset, and then select only the inputs in the fieldset.

Comment: Could you elaboarate a little please? Never used fieldsets. Also, I edited my code

Comment: Well, each you wrap each group in `<fieldset></fieldset>`, you can then say for each fieldset apply that code above.  Thus, events will be limited to the scope of the fieldset.

Comment: so basically we give an id for each fieldset and something like that? then how will i modify this js code?

Comment: Don't have to use an id at all.  `document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')` and loop through the results.  Would you like to edit my answer to reflect this?  I can also edit your question to add a fieldset.

Comment: I've edited your question, will have an updated answer shortly.

Comment: @pratnala, Matsemann keeps undoing my edits.  You will have to make the change yourself if you want it in the question, because I suspect if I edit it again he will simply change it back.

Comment: @pratnala, I have updated my answer and provided a working example.  Please let me know if you have any questions.